# get all bindings of templete in ember

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to get all bindings of all fields or checkboxes of a template in ember ?
The intention is to get them in a generic way, to store them in a generic way in a json object and to send them to the server. The server maps the variable names to the model attributes. Something like I call a function from the controller with the template name and get back all bindings ?

```
get_bindings("templatename":"test_template")
```

How should this method look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really the purpose of two-way bindings in Ember. When you have an object that looks like...

```
person = Ember.Object.create({
  name: 'Jane',
  age: 25
});
```

and a template that looks like...

```
<div>Enter your name here: {{input value=person.name}}</div>
<div>Enter your age here: {{input value=person.age}}</div>
```

...then when you type something new in the boxes, your `person` object automatically gets updated. To persist your person, all you have to do is serialize the `person` object and send it off to the server. There's no asking the template for the new values or manually synchronizing the two.

If you are looking for a more sophisticated way of managing local model lifecycle and interacting with a server that follows certain JSON conventions, check out [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) or any of the other maturing data persistence libraries that are popping up.

Ember doesn't give you a way to easily interact with the view from the controller by design.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is design from the model to the view. Its OK, so I have to create a model.... When I design form the view to the model aka backend then I want just bring the template data to the server and do all the logic there. In the MVC pattern: the "M" is on the server. Perhaps a bad idea to devide MVC.